# Need help making changes to pre-made blog post formats from custom WP Theme

Tags: wordpress, post, formatting, format, blogs

I have purchased a WP theme from Themeforest by Codestag called Shift and its a pretty easy to use and clean UI. It is mostly for blog style posts and they have created pre-made blog posts styles...

For example, an "Audio" post is text and the enbedded audio file. "Video" is the video link and text, "Photo" is obviously the photo and text.

My problem is that these are not customizable and the type of blog posts I create are either audio or video and include a photo of the artists or album art. What code do I need to add to allow this pre-made post to include a photo?  (CODE BELOW)

The second question I have is how can I change the order from Audio file, Title, Text to Title , photo text and audio?

**This is the code for the pre-made blog style: "Audio"**

```
<div class="hentry-inner">

  <div class="entry-wrapper grids">

<?php get_template_part('content', 'meta'); ?>

<div class="entry-content grid-10 clearfix">

  <?php
  $embed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stag_audio_embed', true);

  if(!empty($embed)){
    echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($embed));
  }else{
    stag_audio_player(get_the_ID());
  }

  ?>

  <?php if( is_single() ) { ?>

    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

  <?php } else { ?>

    <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'stag'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php

    if(!is_singular()){
      if(get_the_excerpt() != '') echo "<p>".strip_shortcodes(get_the_excerpt())."</p>";
    }else{
      the_content(__('Continue Reading', 'stag'));
      wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'stag').'</strong> ',   'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number'));
    }

  ?>
</div>
 <span class="bottom-accent"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Much thanks in advance for the help!
-Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have added `the_post_thumbnail` (see [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)) to show a photo above the content:

```
<div class="hentry-inner">

    <div class="entry-wrapper grids">

        <?php get_template_part('content', 'meta'); ?>

        <div class="entry-content grid-10 clearfix">

            <?php
            $embed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stag_audio_embed', true);

            if(!empty($embed)){
                echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($embed));
            }else{
                stag_audio_player(get_the_ID());
            }

            ?>

            <?php if( is_single() ) { ?>

            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php } else { ?>

            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'stag'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php

            if(!is_singular()){
                if(get_the_excerpt() != '') echo "<p>".strip_shortcodes(get_the_excerpt())."</p>";
            }else{

                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                } 

                the_content(__('Continue Reading', 'stag'));

                wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'stag').'</strong> ',   'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number'));
            }

            ?>
        </div>
        <span class="bottom-accent"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This template shows title, featured image, content, audio (in that order):

```
<div class="hentry-inner">

    <div class="entry-wrapper grids">

        <?php get_template_part('content', 'meta'); ?>

        <div class="entry-content grid-10 clearfix">

            <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf(__('Permanent Link to %s', 'stag'), get_the_title()); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <?php

            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }

            the_content(__('Continue Reading', 'stag'));

            wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<p><strong>'.__('Pages:', 'stag').'</strong> ',   'after' => '</p>', 'next_or_number' => 'number'));

            $embed = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_stag_audio_embed', true);

            if(!empty($embed)){
                echo do_shortcode(htmlspecialchars_decode($embed));
            }else{
                stag_audio_player(get_the_ID());
            }

            ?>

        </div>
        <span class="bottom-accent"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

WordPress is very well documented and I advise you to dive into the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page). If you need further customizations you should probably ask and/or hire the theme author to do the modifications for you.

Comment: Great thank you!! for the 2nd set of code can you include allowing a photo in that? so if would be title>Photo>Text>Audio?

That would be fantastic! Again, Thank you for the help!

Comment: Updated code. Don't forget to approve my answer if it solves your issue. ;)

Comment: This is perfect! Last question/problem...This sequence appears only when I click the blog article and takes me to the article page. Any way to have that sequence show on the main blog roll/site?

Comment: Thank you! My rep is too low for chat unfortunately. Any other form of com?